# Chartjs update() function not working after upgrade

Tags: chart.js

I am using Chartjs in a React web app and it was working well with version 2.9.7, which was somehow the default version. Because of one of the extension libraries, I upgraded, first to 4.1.1 and then to 4.3.0, but since then updates do not work:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDclK.png)

So the Chart.update() function is fine, but then it calls an update() function on the options, which does not exist.

Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

When updating the options, I have the following code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nqz9.png)

The creation of the new Chart works fine and the plot shows, but once an option changes, it fails.

**Edit 26/7/2023: now working**

This is the revised, working code:

```
this.chart.data = data;
this.chart.type = (graph === "histogram" ? "bar" : graph);
this.chart.options = config.options;
this.chart.update();
```

Comment: `chart.config` is an internal, undocumented, data structure that is rather the *result* of running `chart.update()`. You probably want to set the input through `chart.options`, see the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#updating-charts)